# Django App incorporated with Multiprocessing using Gevent library facing race condition or may be some thing else

Tags: python, django, python-multiprocessing

I use a global dictionary variable as a cache to keep track of tokens issued for a user on day to day basis. The tokens are getting duplicated. Code logic is given below. I use Django 1.8 with Nginx server spawning multiple Gunicorn threads using Gevent library

```
--------------config.py----------------

    global DOCTOR_TOKEN_CACHE
    DOCTOR_TOKEN_CACHE = {}

---------------------------------------
```

```
    if consultant_code in config.DOCTOR_TOKEN_CACHE:
        config.DOCTOR_TOKEN_CACHE[consultant_code] += 1
    else:
        last_encounter = models.Encounter.objects.filter(
                consultation_date=encounter.consultation_date
            ).exclude(token_no=None).order_by('token_no').last()

        if last_encounter:
           tkn = (last_encounter.token_no+1) if last_encounter.token_no else 1        
        else:
           tkn = 1
        config.DOCTOR_TOKEN_CACHE[consultant_code] = tkn
```

Here even if the cache gets empty there is logic to set the cache back but in spite of all this the tokens are getting duplicated which I'am not able to figure out. Kindly help me out

Comment: Your design is fundamentally flawed. If you want to store data for a user, put it in the database or the session.

Comment: These tokens are stored in corresponding fields of database but since these are issued on per day basis for faster retrieval of last issued token than doing a query I kept a layer of cache which would reduce an extra query

Comment: Then use the cached session backend. There's no way to make this work with global variables.

Comment: Session works like a cache for per logged in user, which I don't want. I want some thing like a global store which can be accessed by any requests

Comment: So just use the cache then.

Comment: Do u mean cache mechanisms like Memcache or something else? Is' nt there any way to set one single Global store in Django app which remains the same for any process requests ?